Geometric interpretation of implicit differentiation
It is well known that, given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, $f'(x_0)$ can be interpreted as the slope of the tangent line to $f$ in $x_0$. What about curves of the form $F(x, y, c)=0$, which cannot be written in the form $y=f(x)$, like the circumference $x^2+y^2-c^2=0$? I know that in this example, to find the tangent in the point $(x_0, y_0)$, one may distinguish the two functions $y=\sqrt{c^2-x^2}$ and $y=-\sqrt{c^2-x^2}$ and then evaluate the derivative in $x_0$ (now ignoring $y_0$, since those are functions), but this procedure doesn't really convince me, as in general one should actually know how to "split up" the curve into two (or, I guess, more) functions. Thus, I have asked my Professor for a general working rule and he answered to use implicit differentiation. For example, suppose we want to find the slope of the tangent to $x^2+y^2-25=0$ in the point $(3,-4)$. Then, differentiating both sides we get $$2x+2y \frac{dy}{dx}=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$$ Hence, the slope in $(3,-4)$ is simply $-\frac{3}{(-4)} = \frac{3}{4}$ . This is indeed the correct answer (in fact, the same I would get if I computed the derivative of $-\sqrt{25-x^2}$ and evaluated it in $x=3$). However, I am very confused about the meaning of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ here, since again this is not a function, and I do not understand the geometric interpretation of implicit differentiation either (that is, how/why this trick works).
In the same way, my Professor showed that for every $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ the curves $$x^2-y^2=a$$ and $$xy=b$$ are orthogonal, since $$x^2-y^2-a=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}$$ and since $$xy-b=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$$
Could you please clarify what I have asked before? Thanks in advance for your precious time and kindness.

This may be a useful way to think about implicit differentiation, if I understand your concern.
The basic assumption is that the terms on both sides of the equals sign are differentiable functions of $x$.  Since the functions are equal, then their derivatives are equal.
For example, to use what you provided above:
$$
y^{2}=c^{2}-x^{2}
$$
The left-hand side is assumed to be a differentiable function of $x$, and so is the right-hand side.
Therefore, differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ one obtains:
$$
2y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=-2x \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}x}=-2x
$$
The left-hand side and right-hand side are still equal.
One uses implicit differentiation exactly in those cases where you don't have $y$ explicitly on one side of the equal sign and some function in terms of $x$ only on the other side.  In other words $y$ only, not something like $y^{2}$ or $\sqrt{y}$ etc.

I see that if two functions are equal, also their derivatives are equal. However, this does not solve my problem. I am not sure you can say that both sides are differentiable "functions" of x, I don't know how to deal with $y^2$

@DavideMasi  Perhaps the way to think about it is the following:  If one varies the value of $x$, does $y^{2}$ change in value?  If so, $y^{2}$ is a function of $x$, and the assumption is that it is differentiable as well.  Maybe this is helpful.

Basically you're saying that I can define the function $z(x)=y^2(x)$, such that $z(x)\ge0$, is that right?

Even though $y$ is not a function of $x,$ we can still say that $y$ is related to $x.$  And, we have a locus of $(x,y)$ pairs that forms a smooth and continuous curve.  Hence, at any point on the curve, we can define a tangent and calculate a derivative.
In the bigger picture, I am not sure that "the slope of the tangent line" is always the best way to think about derivatives.  More often, I think about derivatives as sensitivities.  How sensitive is one variable to changes in the other variable?  I usually know the state of my system in the present, but I want to know what is how robust will the system be to changes in the inputs.  Or, how can I adjust two inputs such that the output remains constant?  This is how I use derivatives in practice.
Anway, one more item to put into your tool kit.
If $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ we can paremterize $x,y$ with $x = r\cos t$ and $y=r\sin t$
$\frac {dx}{dt} = -r\sin t = -y\\
\frac {dy}{dt} = r\cos t = x\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = -\cot t = - \frac {x}{y} $
